# Production build in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Recently i done a project using ionic 3, can anybody help me --aot or --prod which give us production build.

```
cordova run android --aot
```

or

```
cordova run android --prod
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

`--prod` is the option for ionic cli to use aot and minify the code.
`--release` is the option for cordova cli to generate a release build and not a debug one.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/ depends on what all you want to do during build